# An irreducible representation of a finite group whose symmetric square is also irreducible

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, gap

Is there an irreducible representation $V$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) of a finite group $G$ such that $\dim V > 1$ and $\mathrm{Sym}^2V$ is again irreducible?  (I believe that there are examples for compact $G$, such as the fundamental representation of $SU(2)$.)

**Searching for examples:**

Some obvious candidates don't work:

- $G$ cannot be dihedral, as all dihedral irreps are of dimension 1 or 2;
- $G$ cannot be $Q_8$ for analogous reasons;
- $G$ cannot be $S_n$ for $n \le 6$; dimension-counting rules out all irreps except for the two-dimensional irrep of $S_4$, which satisfies $\mathrm{Sym}^2V = 1 \oplus V$;
- $G$ cannot be $A_n$ for $n \le 6$ for similar dimension-counting reasons.

Obviously the Frobenius-Schur indicator of $V$ cannot be 1, but this is sort of tautological.  If $G$ has odd order, then I think the Frobenius-Schur indicator of $V$ must be zero, so perhaps something like the subgroup of $\mathop{PGL}_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ of order 21 is a good place to look.

A suitable GAP query might also produce examples; unfortunately this is beyond my present ability.

**Trying to prove this is impossible:**

I also haven't been able to make any headway on showing that there can be no such $G$.  The obvious strategy would be to find a nice simplification of $$ \left\langle \chi_{\rho}, \chi_{\mathrm{Sym}^2V} \right \rangle, $$ where presumably the clever choice is to take $\rho = V$.  (Taking $\rho = 1$ cannot prove this is impossible, since groups with Frobenius-Schur indicators other than 1 exist.)

Note that if $V$ is not a summand of $\mathrm{Sym}^2V$, we have $$(\dim V)^2 = \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi}_V(g)\chi_V(g^2).$$  This feels possibly helpful in special cases; for example using this formula I think I can (via a sort of "complex rearrangement inequality") rule out this case for $G$ of odd order.

It might be possible to use the hook-length formula to rule out most examples in $S_n$.  The only candidate irreps $V$ of $S_n$ for $n \le 8$ are the quotient of the standard representation by the trivial representation and the tensor product of this representation with the sign representation.  I haven't yet written this down to see if I can make it work; I'd also have to look up a lot about the representations of the symmetric groups to rule out the possibilities that would be left.

Comment: Finite groups where every element has a square root are just the groups with odd order. This is because in such a  group, $g\mapsto g^2$ must be onto, hence $1-1,$ and thus no element other than $1$ can be of order $2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, of course.  I had written that and then gotten confused and worried about the converse to Lagrange's theorem and chose the weaker language.  Thanks, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Are you familiar with the McKay correspondence for finite subgroups of $SU(2)$?

Comment: @Nate Not at all.

Comment: Okay.  Well it gives three examples, all with $V$ two dimensional.  The groups are called the binary tetrahedral, octahedral, and icosahedral groups respectively and they are all finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ -- in fact they are the only finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ other than the cyclic and dihedral groups.

Comment: Explicitly there is a $2$-fold covering from $SU(2)$ to $SO(3)$, and these are the inverse images of the rotation groups of these various platonic solids.

Comment: @Nate How do you get the desired irrep out of this?  I assume you have in mind the standard representation of $SU(2)$, and it seems clear to me that this is still an irrep for these three groups.  But why should I think that the symmetric square of this is irreducible?  After all, the same fact is *not* true for the dihedral groups, which are also finite subgroups of $SU(2)$.  So it seems like you need to use something special about these examples.

Comment: Yes, the standard 2 dimensional representation $V$ coming from the embedding of these groups in $SU(2)$ is what I have in mind.   I'm not really interested in explaining the whole McKay correspondence,  but part of it involves using Dynkin diagrams to characterize the rule for tensoring with this standard representation $V$.  In all three of these cases $V \otimes V$ decomposes as a sum of a trivial representation plus an irreducible $3$ dimensional one.   The trivial piece we know lives in the exterior square (as that's true for $SU(2)$), so the remaining piece must be the symmetric square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention GAP, here is a way how one could test it using the character table functionality:

```
# test for property: Arguments: table, character
test:=function(t,c). 
local p;
  if c[1]=1 or ScalarProduct(c,c)<>1 then return false;fi;
  p:=SymmetricParts(t,[c],2)[1];
  return ScalarProduct(p,p)=1;
end;

# test for group -- any irreducible characetr has property?
gptest:=function ( g )
local t;
  t := CharacterTable( g );
  return ForAny( Irr( t ), x->test( t, x );end );
end;
```

Lets check group up to order 100:

```
gap> g:=OneSmallGroup(Size,[2..100],gptest,true);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> StructureDescription(g); # only makes sense for small orders
"SL(2,3)"
```

and lets check:

```
gap> t:=CharacterTable(g);
CharacterTable( SL(2,3) )
gap> List(Irr(t),x->x[1]);
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 ]
gap> List(Irr(t),x->test(t,x));
[ false, false, false, true, true, true, false ]
```

Thus the 2-dimensional representations of $SL_2(3)$ are an example of minimal order. $SL_2(5)$ is a minimal nonsolvable example (also degree 2), and $SL_3(2)$ is an exampel with character degree 3.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a strategy to find lots of two-dimensional examples!

Let $\rho\colon G\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ be an irreducible, two-dimensional representaiton representation and suppose that the three-dimensional representation $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho)$ is reducible. Then, in particular, $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho)$ contains a $1$-dimensional subrepresentation, $\chi$.

**Claim:** There exists an index two subgroup $H\le G$ and a character $\eta\colon H\to\mathbb C^\times$ such that $\rho = \mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\eta)$.

**Proof:** First note that $\rho \cong \rho^\vee\otimes \det\rho$. This is always true for two-dimensional representations. Hence, we have
$$1=(\rho, \rho) = (\rho\otimes\rho^\vee, 1) = (\rho\otimes\rho, \det(\rho)) = (\mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho) + \det(\rho), \det(\rho)),$$
from which it follows that $(\mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho),\det(\rho)) = 0$. Thus $\det(\rho)\ne \chi$.

Now
$$\begin{align*}(\rho, \rho\otimes\chi\det(\rho)^{-1}) &= (\rho, \rho^\vee\otimes\chi)\\&=(\rho\otimes\rho , \chi)\\&=(\mathrm{Sym}^2(\rho), \chi) = 1\end{align*}$$

Hence, $\rho\cong\rho\otimes\chi'$ for a non trivial character $\chi'$. Taking determinants, it's clear that $\chi'$ has order $2$. Hence, its kernel is a subgroup $H\le G$ of index $2$. It follows from Clifford theory that $\rho|_H$ contains a one-dimensional subrepresentation $\eta$. Finally,
$$1\ge (\rho, \mathrm{Ind}_H^G\eta) = (\rho|_H, \eta) \ge 1$$
and the result follows.

---

So to find an example, just chose any group with a two-dimensional representation whose projective image is not dihedral. As pointed out in the other answer, the smallest example is the two-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_3)$, whose image in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is $A_4$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the phrase "whose projective image is not dihedral"?  I assume by "projective image" you mean the composition with the quotient $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$; what does it mean for a projective representation to be "dihedral"?  Does this just mean that the image in $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ should not be isomorphic to a dihedral group (or a subgroup thereof), or should it be not isomorphic to the image of a subgroup of a dihedral group?

Comment: The finite subgroups of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb C)$ are $C_n, D_n, A_4, S_4, A_5$. I just mean that the projective image should not be a dihedral group (or a cyclic group, but then $\rho$ would be reducible). The point is that dihedral groups have an index $2$ cyclic subgroup. Thus, any irreducible two dimensional representation of with image $D_n$ becomes reducible on an index two subgroup, which is equivalent to being induced from that subgroup.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I'm curious to know if there is any relation between $\eta$ and $\chi$. Thanks!

Comment: @kiddo No connection as far as I know!